# How can you keep a python turtle window open without getting the not responding message

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Can you keep a python turtle window open without getting the not responding message. I made a program where the user types f, b, l, or r and inputs a number to go that distance. However, the turtle window always says "not responding." Anyone know how to fix that issue. I'm not looking for `done()` or `exitonclick()` or `bye()`. None of them work in this situation because I want to use the same window without closing.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle as t
t.showturtle()


def main():
     ask = input("F, B, L, R, or EXIT: ")
     ask = ask.upper()
     if ask == "F":
         x = int(input("How much: "))
         t.forward(x)
         main()
     if ask == "B":
         x = int(input("How much: "))
         t.left(180)
         t.forward(x)
         main()
     if ask == "L":
         x = int(input("How much: "))
         t.left(x)
         main()
     if ask == "R":
         x = int(input("How much: "))
         t.right(x)
         main()
     if ask == "EXIT":
         quit()
     else:
         main()

main()
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: inside `main()` you execute `main()` so you have recursion - it is not good idea - especially that you don't need it. Use `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing `main()` inside `main()` better use `while True` loop

```
import turtle as t

def main():
    while True:
        ask = input("F, B, L, R, or EXIT: ")
        ask = ask.upper()
        if ask == "F":
            x = int(input("How much: "))
            t.forward(x)
        elif ask == "B":
            x = int(input("How much: "))
            t.backward(x)
        elif ask == "L":
            x = int(input("How much: "))
            t.left(x)
        elif ask == "R":
            x = int(input("How much: "))
            t.right(x)
        elif ask == "EXIT":
            return

t.showturtle()
main()
```

But it looks wierd when GUI program uses command line to get value.

But `turtle` has [input methods](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#input-methods) to get value, and you can assign function to key presses.

```
import turtle as t

def on_forward():
    val = t.textinput('Forward', "How much: ")
    if val:
        t.forward(int(val))
    t.listen()

def on_backward():
    val = t.textinput('Backward', "How much: ")
    if val:
        t.backward(int(val))
    t.listen()

def on_left():
    val = t.textinput('Left', "How much: ")
    if val:
        t.left(int(val))
    t.listen()

def on_right():
    val = t.textinput('Right', "How much: ")
    if val:
        t.right(int(val))
    t.listen()

def on_exit():
    t.bye()  

t.showturtle()

# assign functions to keys
t.onkeypress(on_forward, 'f')
t.onkeypress(on_backward, 'b')
t.onkeypress(on_left, 'l')
t.onkeypress(on_right, 'r')
t.onkeypress(on_exit, 'e')

# listen keypresses on main window
t.listen()

# start mainloop which will run functions after key press
t.done()
```

---

**EDIT:** using `tkinter` messagebox to display error message

```
import turtle as t
from tkinter import messagebox

def on_forward():
    val = t.textinput('Forward', "How much: ")
    if val:
        try:
            val = int(val)
            t.forward(val)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Wrong value')
    t.listen()

def on_backward():
    val = t.textinput('Backward', "How much: ")
    if val:
        try:
            val = int(val)
            t.backward(val)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Wrong value')
    t.listen()

def on_left():
    val = t.textinput('Left', "How much: ")
    if val:
        try:
            val = int(val)
            t.left(val)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Wrong value')
    t.listen()

def on_right():
    val = t.textinput('Right', "How much: ")
    if val:
        try:
            val = int(val)
            t.right(val)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Wrong value')
    t.listen()

def on_exit():
    t.bye()  

t.showturtle()

# assign functions to keys
t.onkeypress(on_forward, 'f')
t.onkeypress(on_backward, 'b')
t.onkeypress(on_left, 'l')
t.onkeypress(on_right, 'r')
t.onkeypress(on_exit, 'e')

# catch key presses in main window
t.listen()

# run loop which will execute functions 
t.mainloop()
```